# I am looking for an application to transcribe audio to text

Tags: sound, text

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 as the operating system and LibreOffice as the office suite.

Due to the tasks I perform, it would be useful to install a simple to use application that would allow me to play audio files with the possibility of pausing and/or slowing down the playback.

I need this to be able to proceed with its manual transcription, and thus incorporate the text into my word processor.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may find Parlatype useful, found in the repositories.

Parlatype is a minimal audio player for manual speech transcription.

It plays audio sources to transcribe them in your favorite text application.

And it has integration with LibreOffice.

To install it and test if it meets your expectations, open a terminal and run in it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install  parlatype parlatype-libreoffice-helpers
```

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I already installed it and now it remains to use it.